# How to store server HTTP response header in browser?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, apache

In my PHP application, I get a page by Ajax request and load it into a specific `div` element of the page. I am sending some headers from server in response too.

How to store that headers in browser?

actually as i had mentioned above , through ajax i am loading page and browser url remains unchanged during process , and when i am clicking back button of browser it is redirecting me to very first page of application. all i am trying to do is to store name of requested page by ajax in that browser history which helps back button to navigate functionality .

what i am thinking is possible logically?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/get_headers   or do you mean the headers your server is sending along with the response?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, your `success` callback will have a variable for the server headers. Look in the manual for the right syntax

Comment: yes i am using $.ajax() to make request.how could i will store response headers in browser

Comment: "store headers in browser" what does that mean?

Comment: it means to store some of response  data in browser history

Answer (score 1):

The `success` function called by your jQuery `$.ajax` request will have a `jqXHR` object as its third argument. You can use this object's `getResponseHeader()` method to get the response headers from the server's http response. See the docs for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    success: function(data, responseText, jqXHR) {
        var headers = jqXHR.getResponseHeader();
        // Do what you will with the headers here
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting all header information by using getResponseHeader() but is this is possible to store that headers forcibly to browser?

Comment: You can store them in a javascript variable. I'm not sure what you mean by "forcibly"?

Comment: actually browser maintain history of url requested , i want to store some of response data in that history

Comment: you don't have such 'power' over a users browser. Which I as a user am pleased with.

Comment: @Ekansh if you mean the `History` object then you can manipulate to an extent in some browsers, using the `pushState` method.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history

Comment: actually as i had mentioned above , through ajax i am loading page and browser url remains unchanged during process , and when i am clicking back button of browser it is redirecting me to very first page of application. all i am trying to do is to store name of requested page by ajax in that browser history which helps back button to navigate functionality . what i am thinking is possible logically?

Comment: that's a lot better question than the original, its an XY problem.

Comment: You could still use the new HTML5 history API (http://html5doctor.com/history-api/) to control your navigation state, but it might be a better idea to use the location hash: https://developers.google.com/tv/web/articles/location-hash-navigation